# Restrict user accessing Multiple pages in Web Application Using Java

Tags: java

In our Java based web application we have the concept of Roles and Users. Basically we have many links in our page, and these links can be accessed based on the Role assigned to the user.The Roles and User related information is stored in DB.

During the User Login time we query the DB, get all the related roles and display only the links that are assigned to his Roles. So the user can see only the links he has access.

This way is Working Very Weel. But every time user login the program checks his role level from database.this is burden to database. Please suggest another ways we prevent the accessing multiple links in Web Application.

Comment: Why not just put the roles in a `HttpSession` object and check from that everytime?

Comment: Put the roles into sessions, add a caching process to your DAOs, use existing frameworks such as Spring Security...

Comment: but In our Web Application developed based on JSp,Servlets only.we dont have any idea about Spring

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1) Put the user roles in the session when he is authenticated for the first time and access the session everytime he tries to access a functionality

2) Use a `Map<String, List<Role>>` as a cache and access this map instead of the Database for authenticating a user. Key of the map can be the username. When the user logs in, add the user to the map. When the user logs out or the session expires, remove from the map. Spring Security uses [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) for caching so you could do the same.

```
public void doLogin(HttpSevletRequest request) {
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");
  User user = service.authenticate(username, password);
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("roles", user.getRoles());
}

public void save(HttpServletRequest request) {
  List<Role> roles = request.getSession().getAttribute("roles");
  for(Role role : roles) {
     if(role.getName()=="save") {
        service.save();
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

A trivial example added. For the cache, it'll be a similar except instead of session use Map.

Comment: please share some example of Code that relevant